# Discord.py - Write in a Channel get answer in a specific Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sorting, discord

We have in a server a channel "dump" to dump certain images or messages or reports, and we have in that channel specific threads created.
So the intention is, when sending a "report" (image) send it with a key word.
so the bot pick the message and send it to the specific thread. Like sorting and moving messages.

I have a kind of "algorithm" in mind but I have been unable to code it.

- Entry message in #Dump with Keyword "Test 1"
- Bot reads and picks message ID content and seeks the Keyword "Test 1" to match with Thread named "Test 1" (I imagine is matching "Keyword Test 1" with Thread ID)
- Bot pastes Message with "keyword Test 1" in Test 1 thread
- Bot deletes message in #Dump.

The idea is have the bot sorting the messages one by one to sort to one of the 4 threads on that channel.

Comment: @AlexB I will try to reproduce the idea, is not a problem at all since I've just being struggling to develop it, (sorry delay, internet fluctations are no good)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works but maybe this can guide you:

```
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="")

@Bot.event

async def on_message(message):
  if "Test 1" in message.content:
    given_name = "Test 1"
  thread_get = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.threads, name=given_name)
  thread_id = thread_get.id
  thread = Bot.get_thread(int(thread_id))
  if "Test 1" in message.content:
    await Bot.send_message(message.thread)
    await message.delete()
```

Also see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#thread) to get a better understanding with threads